# how to find a row from an array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

Hi I'm facing with a problem regarding an item of collectionView.

```
  var selectedPartecipants = [NSDate]() // this is the array [Item[0], Item[1] etc... ]

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



            if let deselectedData:NSDate = partecipantsAtEvent[indexPath.row].date! {


                                if let index = selectedPartecipants.indexOf(deselectedData) {

                    selectedPartecipants.removeAtIndex(index)
                  ("item[0] cancelled - I have to search the item in collection view that now is new item[0] in the array")


            }

        }


    }
```

when I deselect item[0] in my collectionView, the code cancel item[0] in my array and want to find the new item in my collectionView the  now is the new item[0] in my array. any ideas?

Comment: I dont really understand what your problem is

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to iterate through all the items in the collection view. So, to find the one that interests you, loop through your partecipantsAtEvent array and look for the item whose date matches your selectedParticpants[0].

Comment: it seems that I missed something.. How can achieve this result?